# List issues facing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am creating script for list but it is all four tab run and when last tab found it's popup it automatically script fails. How to put condition if it is continuously run. Please see my code. http://prntscr.com/10pp6a5

```
WebElement QuizTab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="page-content"]/div/span[1]")); 
List tab = QuizTab.findElements(By.tagName("button")); 
System.out.println(tab.size());

   for(int i=0;i<tab.size();i++) {
       
                   
       System.out.println(tab.get(i).getText());
       tab.get(i).click();
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       driver.navigate().back();
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       
       //if(button.equals(i)) {
       if(tab.get(i).getAttribute("data-toggle").equalsIgnoreCase("modal")){
           driver.findElement(By.linkText("Cancel")).click();
           System.out.println("the system will be continue run");
       }else {
       QuizTab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"page-content\"]/div/span[1]"));
       tab =  QuizTab.findElements(By.tagName("button"));
       }
      
       
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes I have got the solution.

```
  WebElement QuizTab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"page-content\"]/div/span[1]"));
    List<WebElement> tab =  QuizTab.findElements(By.tagName("button"));
    System.out.println(tab);
    System.out.println(tab.size());
    for(int i=0;i<tab.size();i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        String tab1 = tab.get(i).getText();
        tab.get(i).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
                 
        // System.out.println(tab.get(i).getAttribute("data-target"));
                 
        if(tab1.equals("Import")) {
            driver.navigate().refresh();;
            }
        else{
             driver.navigate().back();
            }
                 
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        QuizTab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"page-content\"]/div/span[1]")); //*[@id="page-content"]/div/span[1]/button[5]
        tab =  QuizTab.findElements(By.tagName("button"));
    }
```